# Mobile First 6.3 Context Path Changes

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst

We have an application in Production running using Worklight 6.2.
Now we have a CR in it to add a new module, and server upgraded to Mobile First 6.3. The application was deployed with 6.3 war file and the apps were 6.2, the context path "approvalapp".

Steps are as follows:

1. Deleted the 6.2 apps, deleted the runtime, and created a new runtime with context path as /worklight.
2. Deployed the war file, deployed the adapters and app files. works fine.
3. Later realized, the context path needs to be same as the existing one, so we renamed the context path from "worklight" to "approvalapp".
4. After we restart the server, it shows the error "Runtime Synchronisation failed", and in error logs it says "Host name cannot be empty".
5. When we try with any other context path other than "approvalapp", it works fine.

I cannot provide the log files for now, as we don't have access to copy it form the client system. we assume it to be it still refers to the old apps with 6.2 and fails.

Kindly advice on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Reej I really think you need to open PMRs for these questions. Stack Overfow is meant more for programming than laborious configuration tasks. Also, yes, without logs this question is stuck. Logs and server.xml are a must.

Comment: Noted @IdanAdar. Will ask our client to raise a PMR. Thank you.

Comment: Please be sure to remove this question when you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the context root value in the server.xml, you must make sure that the apps are configured with the name context root value as well, not doing so is a sure way to get apps not connect.

It's unclear why there is a synchronization error on the server, though. That's only the logs will say together with the server.xml file.